# How to reimplement property getter method in subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

I'm new to objective-c and found some OO features I have learned from other language is different in objective-c. The most confusing question for me until now is how to reimplement a property in subclass, or should I do this?

For example, I have two view controllers `GameViewController` and `CardGameViewController`.

```
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController {
    Game *_game;
}
@property (nonatomic) Game *game;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *messageLabel;
@end

@interface CardGameViewController : GameViewController
@property (nonatomic) CardMatchingGame *game;
@end
```

`CardMatchingGame` is derived from `Game`. `@property game` in `GameViewController` is implemented like below:

```
- (Game *)game
{
    if (!_game) {
        _game = [[Game alloc] initWithCardCount:[self.cardButtons count]
                                      usingDeck:[self createDeck]];
    }

    return _game;
}
```

I tried to reimplement `@property game` like below but got a warning in the return clause which said `Incompatible pointer types returning 'Game *' from a function with result type 'CardMatchingGame *'`.

```
- (CardMatchingGame *)game
{
    if (!_game) {

        _game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc] initWithCardCount:[self.cardButtons count]
                                                  usingDeck:[self createDeck]
                                             matchThreshold:self.threshold.selectedSegmentIndex + 2];
    }

    return _game;
}
```

Is this the correct way of reimplementing a property in subclass? If not, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: is `CardMatchingGame` is subclass of `Game`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reimplement like that (well, you could do a ton of casting, but that isn't a good option).

One option is to create the property as `@property (nonatomic) id game;` and then it can hold any type of `Game` class (or subclass) that you have. And, because it is `id` type the compiler will assume that any method you try to call is valid. Obviously you could make mistakes which you won't find till later.

Another, better, option is to add a new property in the subclass as `@property (nonatomic) CardMatchingGame *cardGame;` and, in the subclass, when a new game is created the `CardMatchingGame` instance is stored in both `game` and `cardGame` properties. Now, the superclass has access to `game` and can use it, and the subclass has access to `cardGame`, which is typed as the correct class. So, you have compiler checks and usage of the same instance in both classes. But, you haven't reimplemented a property - you have multiple properties, each doing the appropriate task for their location + purpose.

Comment: If I add a new property to the subclass, it is duplicated. In C++ we can have a pointer which is typed as base class pointer and assign it with a subclass pointer. Why cann't I do this in objective-c?

Comment: You can, and you do. What you can't do is to return that super class pointer when you say you will return a subclass pointer. That is why I say `well, you could do a ton of casting, but that isn't a good option`

Answer (score 0):

If `CardMatchingGame` is a subclass of `Game` you can override `- (Game *)game` and return your `CardMatchingGame` object. Just make sure not to change the return type.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is ivar in parent class `Game *_game;` it produce warning you see. Try to use different name or `id` type for it.

or just cast it before `return (CardMatchingGame *)_game;`